Why is my indexer for DataGrid not being accessed?
I am currently building a small program to read an xml in .NET Core, I am having an issue where my indexer for the data grid is not actually being accessed. I am sure the list have the data is appropriate I am not sure i have created the indexer and bound it correctly.
Creating the DataGrid
private void PopulateDataGrid(List<string> fieldNames)
 {
     DataGrid.Columns.Clear();

     // Add the "Name" column first
     var nameColumn = new DataGridTextColumn
     {
         Header = "Name",
         Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("name")
     };
     DataGrid.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

     // Add other columns
     foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
     {
         var column = new DataGridTextColumn
         {
             Header = fieldName,
             Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding($"Fields[{fieldName}]")
         };
         DataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
     }

     var recordViewModels = records.Select(r => new RecordViewModel(r)).ToList();
     DataGrid.ItemsSource = recordViewModels;
     LogToFile($"Populated DataGrid with {recordViewModels.Count} records.");
 }

Trying to access it
public class RecordViewModel
{
    private readonly string logFilePath = "";

    public Record Record { get; }
    public string Name => Record.Name;

    public Dictionary<string, object> Fields => Record.Fields;

    public RecordViewModel(Record record)
    {
        Record = record;
        LogFields();
    }

    public object this[string fieldName]
    {
        get
        {
            LogToFile("IM INSIDE THE GET");
            if (Fields.ContainsKey(fieldName))
            {
                var fieldValue = Fields[fieldName];
                var fieldType = fieldValue.GetType().Name;
                LogToFile($"Field: {fieldName}, Type: {fieldType}");

                if (fieldValue.GetType() == typeof(FieldGroup))
                {
                    LogToFile($"Field '{fieldName}' identified as FieldGroup using exact type match");
                    return ""; // FieldGroup is shown as blank
                }
                else if (fieldValue is FieldGroup fieldGroup)
                {
                    LogToFile($"Field '{fieldName}' identified as FieldGroup using 'is' operator");
                    return ""; // FieldGroup is shown as blank
                }
                else if (fieldValue is List<string> fieldList)
                {
                    LogToFile($"Field '{fieldName}' identified as FieldList");
                    return string.Join(", ", fieldList); // FieldList as concatenated string
                }
                else
                {
                    LogToFile($"Field '{fieldName}' is of type {fieldType}");
                    return fieldValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LogToFile($"Field not found: {fieldName}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

DataGrid in Xaml i am filling
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,50,10,10" MouseLeftButtonUp="DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <!-- Columns will be generated programmatically -->
</DataGrid>

I have ensured the data is accurate and building correctly.
